# ¿Cómo puedo añadir una foreign key para un autoincremental en laravel 5.6?

Tags: sql, laravel, integer

Veréis, estoy creando una intranet en laravel, y no sé como puedo hacer para añadir una `foreign key` de la siguiente manera:

Tengo una tabla con un ID autoincremental como `primary key` y quiero que una segunda tabla me coja ese ID para rellenar ese campo.

Yo entiendo que la `foreign` debe ser de tipo *integer* para coger el ID, no?

Adjunto mi código de laravel de las tablas que quiero unir:

*Tabla 1:*

```
Schema::create('departments', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('department');
            $table->timestamps();
});
```

*Tabla 2:*

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('username')->unique();
            $table->string('email');
            $table->string('password');
            $table->string('photo_profile');
            $table->string('design_web')->default('white');
            $table->integer('department_id');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->foreign('department_id')
            ->references('id')
            ->on('departments')
            ->onDelete('cascade');
```

La idea es asignar a un usuario un departamento concreto. El error que recibo al hacer la migración en laravel es el siguiente:

> 1   PDOException::("SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add
>   foreign key constraint")
>         C:\laragon\www\intranet\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:458
>
> 2   PDOStatement::execute()
>         C:\laragon\www\intranet\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:458

Estoy un poco perdido, es mi primer proyecto en laravel y soy novato en esto.

¡Gracias por vuestra ayuda!

Comment: Elimina en el phpmyadmin manualmente todas las tablas y vuelve a ejecutar la migracion

Comment: EN que orden estan tus migraciones? es decir cual archivo de migración aparece primero?

Answer (score 1):

Intenta creando tu 'department_id' como unsignedInteger
así:

```
$table->unsignedInteger('department_id');
```

Si en la tabla **departments**, el **id** se creó con **autoincrements**, eso significa que es equivalente a un **unsignedInteger** (el valor nunca es negativo).

Si el tipo de dato de **department_id** no es igual al tipo de **id** de **departments**, entonces no se puede crear la foránea.

Comment: @ferran.hierro Lo que menciona Julio es cierto. Como observación haría que también es importante el orden en el que se ejecutan las migraciones (primero debes crear la tabla `departments` y luego `users`, pues ésta última referencia a la primera)